# Libraries for Embedding WLST to Java

Tags: java, jython, wlst

I am quite new to WLST. I am trying this example from here -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs92/config_scripting/using_WLST.html#wp1075595

This requires me to import following classes -

```
import weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter;
import org.python.util.InteractiveInterpreter;
```

Could someone tell which jar I need to add to the build path in order to import  these classes. I added **weblogic-classes.jar** and I don't see any compile time errors. But it fails during runtime with following exception -

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   weblogic/management/scripting/utils/WLSTMsgTextFormatter  at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTUtilHelper.(WLSTUtilHelper.java:33)
>     at
>   weblogic.management.scripting.utils.WLSTInterpreter.(WLSTInterpreter.java:80)

Would appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the environment variables  CLASSPATH with WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar;. at the end dot is must for Windows you could writ as :

```
set WL_HOME=c:\fmw\wlserver
set CLASSPATH=%WL_HOME%\server\lib\weblogic.jar;.
```

On the Linux /UNIX platforms

```
export WL_HOME=/u01/app/fmw/wlserver
export CLASSPATH=$WL_HOME/server/lib/weblogic.jar:.
```

After setting in your command prompt you can proceed with your Embedded WLST program. Lets know your feedback after using above!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Before you run your Java program with WLST embedded, call the script

```
WL_HOME/server/bin/setWLSEnv.sh (or setWLSEnv.cmd on Windows)
```

which sets the CLASSPATH for you. Where `WL_HOME` is the installation directory of WebLogic.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the below jars and settings as well

jython.jar:

wlfullclient.jar

Check link on how to create it
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/client/jarbuilder.html

From dir
C:\XXXXXXX\Oracle\Middleware\modules

com.oracle.cie.comdev_6.3.0.0.jar

com.oracle.cie.config-wls_7.1.0.0.jar:

com.oracle.cie.config_7.1.0.0.jar:

com.bea.core.xml.xmlbeans_2.1.0.0_2-5-1.jar:

com.oracle.cie.config-wls-schema_10.3.4.0.jar:

com.oracle.cie.wizard_6.1.0.0.jar

These properties need to be set as well

-Dprod.props.file=props.txt

-Dbea.home=

-Dweblogic.home=/Users/xxxxxx/Projects/WebLogicServer/